# Create a folder with files in git repo

Tags: linux, git, macos, github

I have a problem while pushing folder with HTML files to my GitHub repository via terminal on macOS. After pushing, my folder doesn't open and I can't see what is inside it. Moreover, when I tried it on Linux, it worked well, but on my mac it doesn't:

[image]

`week0` and `week1` don't open, but `week2` does. At first I created `week1` from Linux, then pushed `week2` via Mac and it opened my folder, but closed `week1`. After I pushed `week0` via mac and it doesn't open either.

Comment: Are you sure you pushed on master branch?

Comment: `week0` and `week1` have the submodule icon displaying, are they imported from another repo?

Comment: @Zooly Yes, i entered -push u origin master

Comment: @LightBender no, they are from local system

Comment: symlinks maybe?